# Keep the toolbar at the top like in portrait orientation when I change the orientation to landscape Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is it possible to keep the toolbar at the top like in portrait orientation when I changed the orientation landscape? Like at picture below, the toolbar (with 3 black bars) still at the top while the blurred table is in landscape orientation.

[image]

Comment: I think that was about to completely change screen orientation. At least, is it possible to keep the toolbar at the top like in potrait orientation when I changed the orientation landscape? Like at picture above, the toolbar (with 3 black bars) still at the top while the blurred table is in landscape orientation.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, now. You might want to clarify that in your question. I read it as you wanted the layout to rotate to landscape while the device stayed in portrait.

Comment: did you tried setting rotation to your layout? there is a method which can be useful `yourLayout.setRotation(90.0f);`